# Inserting imageView from a JSON object, image file on the internet

Tags: android, json

I am showing JSON objects on a list view in Android.

This is the piece of code  I am using to populate the rows:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;

        if(v == null) {
            LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            v = li.inflate(R.layout.ofertas_app_custom_list, null);           
        }

        Ofertas_Application app = items.get(position);

        if(app != null) {
            ImageView icon = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            TextView titleText = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            TextView direccionText = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            TextView valoracionText = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView3);

            if(titleText != null) titleText.setText(app.getNombreEmpresa());//populate textView1

            if (direccionText !=null) direccionText.setText(app.getDireccionEmpresa());//populate textView2

    //what I need comes here, app.getImagenEmpresa stores the image name, and the URL to the image is http://mujercanariasigloxxi.appgestion.eu/imagenes

        }

        return v;
    }
```

Now I need to populate imageView1  with an image which name is stored at

```
app.getImagenEmpresa()
```

Any help is welcome. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do as below :

```
ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
try {
    URL url = new URL("Your URL");
    //try this url = "http://0.tqn.com/d/webclipart/1/0/5/l/4/floral-icon-5.jpg"
    HttpGet httpRequest = null;

    httpRequest = new HttpGet(url.toURI());

    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) httpclient
            .execute(httpRequest);

    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    BufferedHttpEntity b_entity = new BufferedHttpEntity(entity);
    InputStream input = b_entity.getContent();

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);

    img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

} catch (Exception ex) {

}
```

Or use [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) / [Volley](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/) for the same and some extra features like caching.

Comment: I have included your proposal into my code, using the test URL, but the image view doesn't changed to the image floral-icon-5.jpg, the default image set in the layout file is showed instead.